# Erase comments using javascript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

How to remove the comments using regexp if the code contains some regexp itself:

```
1. function fun(arg) {
2.      // 1. remove comments
3.      arg = arg.replace(/\/\/[\w\s]+$/gm, '');
4.      arg = arg.replace(/\/\*[-\s\w,\(\)]+\*\//, '');          
5.      arg = arg.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, ''); // 2. remove trailing spaces          
6.      arg = arg.replace(/\n/g, ' '); // 3. remove line breaks
7. }
```

The following trial would cut off the code in line 4... arg = arg.replace(//*[-\s\w,()]+*\

```
fun.toString().replace(/\/\/.+/gm, '')
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this in general -- what if a string had // in it, like `myString = 'foo//bar';`? You could do something like only match `//` if the previous character was `;` (hoping that the coder terminates lines with ;), { or } etc but that seems kludgy. I think your best hope is to (say) enforce a space (or start-of-line) before the `//` as most people put a space between code and in-line comments, though of course not all do.

Comment: I think you will need a parser. Someone recommended [esprima](http://esprima.org) to me

Answer (score 0):

This would work with the example, though I am not sure if I would miss other cases

```
fun.toString().replace(/[^\\]\/\/.+/gm, '')
```